# Genymotion Translation installed, but the apk still doesn't get installed

Tags: android, arm, apk, genymotion

My virtual device is android 7.0
Genymotion is 3.1 linux x64

I installed the Genymotion Translation 7.X through drag and drop.

The output of the following command is

```
adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist
```

Output

```
x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi
```

So, translation has been correctly installed.

But dragging and dropping the apk still gives the following error.

> An error occured while deploying the file. This probably means that
>   the app contains ARM native code and your Genymotion device cannot run
>   ARM instructions. You should either build your native code to x86 or
>   install an ARM translation tool in your device.

I tried `adb push` that file to `/data/app`,

```
adb push my-apk /data/app
```

the apk is there in /data/app but

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

doesn't show it.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3):

Is your APK file architecture arm64? If so, it will not work with Genymotion, even with ARM translation tools: they only translate arm and armv7 (32bits).

Comment: which emulator can be used for arm64?

Comment: As far as I know, no Android emulator supports arm64 for the moment.